# Is it possible to create an alternative Android assistant app?

Tags: android, google-assistant-sdk

When I press the home key for long time a default assist app launches.
Is it possible to create my own Android assistant app which launch instead of the default assistant?

Comment: something like that is probably built into the OS itself, so it depends

Comment: You can create your own assistant app using the Assist API. Whether it launches is up to the user -- the user has to opt into using your assistant via a screen in Settings.

Answer (score 2):

You can, as you can build your own [VoiceInteractionService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/voice/VoiceInteractionService) which can be activated in the same way and provide contextual results through a voice query.

Answer (score -1):

In order to change the Home button default assistant on Android devices, open your Settings and search for "Device assistant app". This will show you a screen with multiple areas of customization.

Selecting the "Device assistant app" button will take you to a menu which will let you select between a number of apps based on what you have available on your device.